# Need help finding a pre-run meal

Tags: running, diet, beginners

So I've been working out a lot within the last couple months. Most of my cardio has been elliptical, stationary bike, rowing machine and basketball. I've felt a ton of progress in my conditioning and VO2 has shown improvement too. I really want to get into running but I'm having a lot of trouble with it. I don't think that it's my physical ability holding me back or a mental barrier by possibly nutritional. What are some meals that I can have that will provide me really good nutritional value, aren't too heavy and won't ruin my diet.

Currently I eat some peanut butter crackers and I have some unsweet ice tea before hand as hydration and a little caffeine to boost me up. I'm also worried about my sugar intake so I've tried to cut out all of that especially processed sugar. I try to run about 3 miles 2-3 times a week and I'd say I'm able to complete it without stopping about once at a 10:00min/mile pace. I'm not worried about the pace but I'd like to be able to get to a place where I can finish without stopping every time.

Comment: I don’t know how long you’re going to be running for, so it’s hard to gauge your calorie burn. I go out for fairly lengthy periods of time and can expect to burn near 1000 calories on the run. Way more if I’m doing a bike/run brick. I love a piece of toasted whole grain bread, slathered with peanut butter, with a little honey on top. I wouldn’t call it perfectly healthy because of the sugar in the honey, but I expect I’m burning that all off anyway. I always seem to have plenty of energy with that particular snack.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It might help if you outlined the problems you are having running, what your current diet is. Otherwise this is mostly a request for recipes, which would be off topic.